# How to ordering emails using EWS managed API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I want to ordering by datetime/sender/subject emails which populated by EWS managed API using C#.I'm populating emails like below-

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
 var itemView = new ItemView(pageSize, offset, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);
 FindItemsResults<Item> fiitems = null;
 fiitems = service.FindItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, userMailbox), itemView);
 service.LoadPropertiesForItems(fiitems.Items, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check Glenns answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266090/ews-finditems-orderby-sort-by-emailmessageschema-from-incorrect-order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(10, 0, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);
view.OrderBy.Add(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, SortDirection.Ascending);
```